# GC cleans Tenured Gen heap quite rarely

Tags: java, garbage-collection

According to New Relic [reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJB6s.png), Tenured Gen heap is cleaned pretty rarely, and from time to time application used heap reaches ~80% of max heap, but I want it to reach ~70% and get cleaned. How to properly adjust GC to avoid reaching 80% heap usage? I have default GC settings on start.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from having another 10% of the reserved heap memory being completely unused?

Comment: It's more about control, 80% can be okay, but I want to be sure it won't get 90%. And instead of increasing max heap memory I want to control GC. If old heap cleaning executes once in a few days, it won't affect performance dramatically if it will be cleaned more frequently. But probably it's a bad practice, so I'm seeking for advice

Comment: But your report says that everything is fine and there is no danger of reaching 90%. Even if it ever reaches 90% one day, it wouldn’t harm; it would just be a signal that *then* you may consider altering the configuration to avoid getting too close to 100%. In fact, with the default settings, the GC will do that tuning automatically.

Comment: By using Java you are actually leaving a lot of control to the JVM. Unless you have identified an specific issue leave it as it is.